# VBA Array Comparison

Tags: arrays, vba, comparison

I am trying to compare columns 1,2, and 3 to columns 4,5,and 6. Columns 1 and 4 are times, but they do not always line up, so I would like there to be an error margin of 2 seconds. Columns 2 and 5 and 3 and 6 should always match exactly. I would like the code to run down column 1 and check if any values within column 3 are within the range. If they are, I would like to see if the other two values match. If they all match, I would like to paste some of the values from array1 and array2 on "Sheet2." The key is that I would like it to run fast. Below I've posted what I have so far. Any suggestions/critiques/overhauls would be extremely welcome!

Thanks,

Sam

```
Sub Comp()

Dim array1() As Variant
Dim array2() As Variant
Dim last1 As String
Dim last2 As String
Dim C As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim high As Long
Dim low As Long
Dim x As Boolean

last2 = Sheets("Comparison").Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row
last1 = Sheets("Comparison").Range("BV10000").End(xlUp).Row
C = 0
A = 0

ReDim array1(C To last1, 3)
ReDim array2(A To last2, 5)

For C = 0 To last1

array1(C, 1) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("A" & C + 2).Value
array1(C, 2) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("D" & C + 2).Value
array1(C, 3) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("G" & C + 2).Value

high = array1(C, 1) + (1.15740740740741E-05 * 2)  '2 seconds
low = array1(C, 1) + (1.15740740740741E-05 * 2)  '2 seconds
x = False

For A = 0 To last2

array2(last2, 1) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("I" & A + 2).Value
array2(last2, 2) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("K" & A + 2).Value
array2(last2, 3) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("M" & A + 2).Value
array2(last2, 4) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("J" & A + 2).Value
array2(last2, 5) = Sheets("Comparison").Range("L" & A + 2).Value

If array1(C, 2) = array2(A, 2) And array1(C, 3) = array2(A, 3) And high >= array2(A, 1) And array2(A, 1) >= low Then

x = True

If x = True Then

Exit For

If x = True Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = array2(A, 4).Value And Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = array2(A, 5).Value

Else

Next A

Exit For

For C = 0 To last1

If x = True Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A100000").End(x1up).Offset(1, 0) = array1(C, 1).Value And Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B100000").End(x1up).Offset(1, 0) = array1(C, 3).Value

Next C

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are several typos in your code, I've corrected as below.
2. The less i/o needed, the better performance. And it's better to read several data once like 500 rows a time than read 1 row, do something, read next row, do something. Therefore it's better to read all data into arrays and save the matches in the 3rd array. After all comparisons are done, we write it back to the worksheet then. [Ref](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2017/04/excel-vba-read-and-write-performance-test.html)

Code as below, not tested.

```
Sub Comp()

    Dim array11, array12, array13 As Variant
    Dim array2 As Variant
    Dim arrayMatch As Variant
    Dim arrayTmp As Variant
    Dim last1 As String
    Dim last2 As String
    Dim C As Integer
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim matchCount As Long

    With Sheets("Comparison")
        last1 = .Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row
        last2 = .Range("I100000").End(xlUp).Row
        '[1]
        array11 = .Range("A2:A" & last1 + 2).Value
        array12 = .Range("D2:D" & last1 + 2).Value
        array13 = .Range("G2:G" & last1 + 2).Value

        array2 = .Range("I2:L" & last2 + 2).Value
    End With

    '[2]
    ReDim arrayMatch(1 To 500, 1 To 4) As Variant

    For C = LBound(array11) To UBound(array11)
        For A = LBound(array2) To UBound(array2)
            If array12(C) = array2(A, 3) And array13(C) = array2(A, 5) And Abs(DateDiff("s", array11(C), array2(A, 1))) <= 2 Then
                matchCount = matchCount + 1

                'Check the result array is fulled or not
                If matchCount > UBound(arrayMatch) Then
                    '[3]
                    arrayTmp = arrayMatch
                    ReDim arrayMatch(1 To UBound(arrayTmp) + 500, 1 To 4)
                    For i = LBound(arrayTmp) To UBound(arrayTmp)
                        arrayMatch(i, 1) = arrayTmp(i, 1)
                        arrayMatch(i, 2) = arrayTmp(i, 2)
                        arrayMatch(i, 3) = arrayTmp(i, 3)
                        arrayMatch(i, 4) = arrayTmp(i, 4)
                    Next i
                End If

                arrayMatch(matchCount, 1) = array11(C)
                arrayMatch(matchCount, 2) = array13(C)
                arrayMatch(matchCount, 3) = array2(A, 2)
                arrayMatch(matchCount, 4) = array2(A, 4)

                Exit For
            End If
        Next A
    Next C

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A100000").End(x1up).Offset(1, 0).Resize(matchCount, 4).Value = arrayMatch
End Sub
```

1. If the range is continuous, assigning the values to one array at one time is the best way. However in your case they are separated columns, I set 3 arrays to store the values. Same reason for array2, read the value at once is better than looping. And there is no need to change the column order in case you need a better performance. Note that assigning array values like this, the array will be 1-based.
2. I guess about 500 matches. You can feel free to adjust it.
3. Since nobody can predict that how many matches actually will there be, there is a possibility that the `arrayMatch` is not big enough. It is surely a waste of both time and memory, so deciding a good size of `arrayMatch` is important.